# Html5 desktop notification php/mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, html

hello as described from the title above , I have a website where users enter their datas to the database so what I'm looking for now is when a data is inserted to the database for each user he will receive a desktop notification just like the one of facebook , I know how html5 desktop notifications works but I don't know how to make it work for each user when new data is inserted to database, Please I need someone to guide me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with COMET Programming or Socket Programming. My choice would be Comet Programming because it's easier than Sockets. Now what you are going to do is just you will change a files last edit time, believe or not that's all. The algorithm is easy, you will create a php file for this purpose everyone will connect this file via Javascript and you will get your results when anyone inserts data.

You can check Comet Programming here :

http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

By the way Facebook is still using COMET Programming for every notification,time-line operations and message operations.Also Gmail using it for Live Mail System.

Comment: can you give me some example of desktop notifications for my website